# Why isn't the cout overflow in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code patch running on my ubuntu20.04, compiled by gcc-9.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint16_t a = 0xFFFF;
    uint16_t b = 1;

    uint16_t ret = a + b;
    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
    std::cout << ret << std::endl;
}
```

I expect both of the results are overflowed, but the running results show that only the second one overflows and the first one can get correct result.

What makes them behave differently. The right value of the `+` operation should also be `uint16_t`, so why the first `cout` can get the right result?

P.S., when I change the type from `uint16_t` to `uint32_t`, both of them are overflowed.

Comment: Google "integer promotion".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do `a + b` the operands will undergo [arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) which will [promote](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) the values to `int` types.

So `a + b` is really something like `static_cast<int>(a) + static_cast<int>(b)` and the result will of course be an `int`.

Promotion only happens with types smaller than `int` (so `short` or `char`). Values that already are `int` (or larger) will not be promoted.